# Highlight multiple points on a plot: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to highlight max, min values and points of highest residuals. I am able to create all these independently. See code below:

```
library(alr4)

library(tidyverse)

library(broom)

library(ggplot2)

modelUN <- lm(log(fertility) ~ log(ppgdp), data = UN11)

#For Max Fertility

UN11 %>% mutate(has_highest_fertility = fertility == max(fertility), has_lowest_fertility = fertility == min(fertility)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = ppgdp, y = fertility, color = has_highest_fertility)) + geom_point()

#For Min Fertility

UN11 %>% mutate(has_highest_fertility = fertility == max(fertility), has_lowest_fertility = fertility == min(fertility)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = ppgdp, y = fertility, color = has_lowest_fertility)) + geom_point()
```

Similarly, I can extract residuals and do this. But I'm interested in doing all this in one plot. And wanting to label them. So lowest fertility will have a string, "Lowest Fertility" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one attempt: assign a `lbl` to all points, `NA` for most and something meaningful for the two extremes. (This allows you to have an arbitrary number of labels.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    lbl = case_when(
      row_number() == which.min(hp) ~ "Lowest HP",
      row_number() == which.max(hp) ~ "Highest HP",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  ) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = !is.na(lbl))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = lbl), hjust = -0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

[image: ggplot2 of mtcars with min and max HP highlighted and labeled]

Comment: Okay this is awesome!